# Confused by pandas dtype conversion to np.float16 value 2053 becomes 2052

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was trying to reduce memory consumption by downcasting float data types.

I checked the range of `np.float16`:

```
np.finfo(np.float16)
finfo(resolution=0.001, min=-6.55040e+04, max=6.55040e+04, dtype=float16)
```

This shows `-6.55040e+04 < 2053 < 6.55040e+04`

Now:

```py
s = pd.Series([2051,2052,2053,2054])
s.astype(np.float16)

0    2052.0
1    2052.0
2    2052.0
3    2054.0
```

Why is it so?

**UPDATE**
Borrowing documentation from `np.finfo`

```
numpy.finfo
class numpy.finfo[source]
Machine limits for floating point types.

Parameters: 
dtype : float, dtype, or instance

Kind of floating point data-type about which to get information.

Attributes

eps (float) The smallest representable positive number such that 1.0 + eps != 1.0. Type of eps is an appropriate floating point type.
epsneg  (floating point number of the appropriate type) The smallest representable positive number such that 1.0 - epsneg != 1.0.
iexp    (int) The number of bits in the exponent portion of the floating point representation.
machar  (MachAr) The object which calculated these parameters and holds more detailed information.
machep  (int) The exponent that yields eps.
max (floating point number of the appropriate type) The largest representable number.
maxexp  (int) The smallest positive power of the base (2) that causes overflow.
min (floating point number of the appropriate type) The smallest representable number, typically -max.
minexp  (int) The most negative power of the base (2) consistent with there being no leading 0’s in the mantissa.
negep   (int) The exponent that yields epsneg.
nexp    (int) The number of bits in the exponent including its sign and bias.
nmant   (int) The number of bits in the mantissa.
precision   (int) The approximate number of decimal digits to which this kind of float is precise.
resolution  (floating point number of the appropriate type) The approximate decimal resolution of this type, i.e., 10**-precision.
tiny    (float) The smallest positive usable number. Type of tiny is an appropriate floating point type.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about `min` or `max`, which determine the lowest and highest values a `float16` can take respectively, but `resolution`, or the least difference between two values before they are considered identical.

`finfo` shows that the resolution of `float16` is `0.001`, or 4 significant figures. The digit `2` in your case is the 4th significant figure.

Comment: Then, how to find the maximum/minimum value supported by `np.float16`? It would be easier to check and set data types?

Comment: The values reported by `finfo` *are* accurate. The issue here is not that your value is too high or too low, but that *you have not enough bits to differentiate between two "nearby" values*.

Comment: This means np.float16 can not work for any values more than 3 integers?  i.e. works for `xxx` but not `xxxx` ?

Comment: @astro123 Kind...of...it also depends on the absolute value of your numbers. In general, though, I would *not* recommend `float16` for most `pandas` work. Are you really that short of memory?

Comment: No, I have 16GB RAM on my macpro, I was just working with 1GB dataset, memory was not the problem, but I was confused by the documentation of `np.finfo`, IMHO Its better to save memory when you can. Probably I should create an issue in numpy github.